# Creating test utilities for spring tests in a separate module?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have 2 adjacent classes for my integration tests with the following signatures:

```
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class AuthenticationTransformationTest extends AbstractKafkaIntegrationTest {
```

```
@DirtiesContext(classMode = DirtiesContext.ClassMode.AFTER_EACH_TEST_METHOD)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {KafkaIntegrationConfig.class})
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public abstract class AbstractKafkaIntegrationTest {
```

The idea is -- within this repo, we have N modules that utilize Spring. I'm looking to have a `util` module that contains the Abstract class so others within their own modules can extend from it and run their tests. When moving the abstract class to another module, I have a bunch of errors getting the annotations to resolve, despite adding the required dependencies, etc.

What is the best, recommended way to have a util module that *only* provides the testing utility class? Do I need to throw an @Configuration annotation somewhere for this to be picked up correctly?

Edit: I've moved the classes to test dir - it helped resolve the annotation issue, but the dependency on the test util isn't resolving via Gradle:

```
.
├── moduleA
│   └── test
│       └── java
│           └── com
│               └── thing
│                   └── integration
│                       └── my-test.java
└── moduleB
    └── test
        └── java
            └── com
                └── thing
                    └── test-util.java
```

preamble of `moduleA`

```
plugins {
    id "org.springframework.boot" version "$springBootVersion"
    id "com.google.cloud.tools.jib" version "$jibVersion"
    id "application"
    id "java"
}

group "com.thing.test"
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11

dependencies {
    testImplementation(testFixtures(project(':moduleB')))
```

I've tried just:

```
    testImplementation(project(':moduleB'))
```

and get the same issue

Comment: so why not extract this into a separate test module then? Or am I missing something?

Comment: if I have moduleA with testX and moduleB with testUtility, do you know how I can properly add the dependency? I'm using gradle I can't get it to resolve.

Comment: it is a bit hard to tell without knowing more details, but inner dependencies can be specified like this, for example: `project(':rest') {
    dependencies {
        implementation project(':services-api')
        implementation project(':services-impl')
        implementation project(':models')
    }
}` (literally taken from our code base)

Comment: let me update the original post with directory structure and example

Comment: updated the OP to contain example

Comment: You need to tell gradle that `moduleA` depends on `moduleB` via `testImplementation`, like I've shown you in the example above, that should work.

Comment: is that not what I've done?

Comment: what if you change it to `project(':moduleA') {
    dependencies {
        testImplementation project(':moduleB')
    }
}`?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230195/discussion-between-john-and-eugene).

Comment: I am glad you got it resolved, in the meanwhile I really think this is a duplicate as stated in the chat we had.